# Make numbers from 1-10 with 5 3s

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

In [this puzzle book](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%93%88%E4%BD%9B%E7%BB%99%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F%E5%81%9A%E7%9A%84450%E4%B8%AA%E5%A4%9A%E5%85%83%E6%99%BA%E8%83%BD%E8%AE%AD%E7%BB%83%E6%B8%B8%E6%88%8F), I came across a question that goes like this:

> Make the numbers from 1-10 using 5 3s.

Rules:

> You are only allowed to use the four basic arithmetic operators ($+, -, \times, \div$). You are allowed to use brackets.

Here is what I have so far:

> $3+3-3+3-3=3$ 
>  $3+3+3+3-3=9$ 
>  $(3\times3)+(3\div3)-3=7$ 
>  $3\div3+3+3+3=10$ 
>  $3+3\div3-3+3=4$

Can someone help me figure out the rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complete answer(thanks to [Ross Millikan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/73/ross-millikan) and [BAWS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/72780/baws)):

> $3-3\div3-3\div3=1$ 
>  $3-3\div3\times3\div3=2$ 
>  $3+3-3+3-3=3$ 
>  $3+3\div3-3+3=4$ 
>  $((3\times3)+(3+3))\div3=5$ 
>  $(3\times3)-(3-3)-3 = 6$ 
>  $(3\times3)+(3\div3)-3=7$ 
>  $3+3+((3+3)\div3)=8$ 
>  $3+3+3+3-3=9$ 
>  $3\div3+3+3+3=10$

Answer (score 3):

> $((3\times3)+(3+3))\div3 = 5$ 
>  $(3\times3)-(3-3)-3 = 6$

I'll leave the rest with this new way of looking at it.

Comment: Hi, on this site, for answers, you need to hide them in spoiler blocks(>!) most of the times. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here are $1,2$ and $8$

> $$3-\frac 33 - \frac 33 =1$$ 
>  $$3-\frac 33 \cdot \frac 33=2 $$
>  $$3+3+\frac{3+3}3=8$$

Answer (score 1):

We obtain the missing numbers from the following.

> $(3-3)\times3+\frac{3}{3}=1$ 
>  
>  $3-3+\frac{3+3}{3}=2$ 
>  
> $3+\frac{3}{3}+\frac{3}{3}=5$ 
>  
>  $3+3+3\times (3-3)=6$